# Is it OK to use previous Handler in Activity created before onDestroy() onPause()?

Tags: android

Is it OK to reuse a Handler object in the next life of Activity which was previously created in its previous session (before onPause, onDestroy()) ?

Like I create a Handler in Activity propagate it to other objects elsewhere, the Activity dies or pauses, then comes to life again and use the old handler ?

```
    // In the oncreate() method I have this code to recreate handler every time
    // Then I set the handler to a static Global object 
    // Other Objects use the global object's static method to get 
    //fresh handler every timebefore calling sendMessage()

        /**
     * Set up handler 
     */     
    Handler h = new Handler(new Callback() 
    {           
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) 
        {
            handleServiceMessage(msg);
            return true;
        }
    }); 


    uiglobal = new UIGlobals(h);
```

UiGlobals is declared as

```
 private static UIGlobals uiglobal = null;
```

Not sure if the above approach is correct ..

my GlobalUI class looks like this

```
    public class UIGlobals 
    {
         private static Handler handler = null; 
         public UIGlobals(Handler h)
        {
            handler = h;
        }   
        public static Handler getHandler()
        {
            return handler;
        }    
    }
```

Comment: In general, possibly, so long as the old Handler doesn't keep the old Activity alive (through a pending callback, etc.).  A code example might allow for a more concrete response.

Comment: I have updated the question, please have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have build your custom Handler class this should work but if you have defined your customized handler in your activity you have to unregister all handler messages in onPause. Otherwise you get a null pointer exception.
But i dont know in whick scenario you need this functionality... I normalley use Handler for UI access but for communication between activity and logic observer pattern.

Comment: Basically this is for communication bw activity and threads in service. The threads sendMessage() data back to activity via handler refs they have.  When Activity dies and then comes to life, it has no idea of recent message posted by the thread in service.

Comment: i am using broadcasts for service <-> Activity / Thread communication with custom intent filter. Works very nice!

Comment: Any example would be nice and helpful

Comment: There are so many examples online.

http://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Googles_Android/_BroadcastReceiver is one of thousand.
you can use a receiver in your service and a receiver in you app (also in an activity is possible) so you have a two way communication.

Answer (score 0):

If your handler is static and the `Application` (not the activity) hasn't been removed from memory, next time activity starts, static objects will be there.

If your handler is static and the `Application` has been removed from memory (i.e. service, threads, etc. are all stoped and you exit the only active activity) the next time you start activity, the `Aplication`object will be restarted and static objects will be recreated.

If your handler is not static, the you should be recreating it everytime you create activity, and of course, you will get a new one.

You need to post code or be more specific on your situation, if you want to have a more concrete answer.

Comment: I have put up some code, please take alook.Assumption is the process is not dead, only activity is gone, my handler is stored every time in onCreate in a new Global object's static variable

Comment: The code you post is not reusing the previous handler. As you said, you create a new handler in `onCreate()` and assign it to `UIGlobals`. As soon as you assign a new handler, the old one is gone. Also, from code above, the handler linking to your activity will be kept in user by the service when you activity die, and this may result in a memory leak.